Initiating a conversation from python telegram bot on scheduled time
I apologise in advance for not providing code. I will try to add it tomorrow but I’m not near it right now and thinking about how to solve this is keeping me up.
This is my code currently:
#Return datetime + offset in seconds
def TimeOffset(sample):
    return datetime.datetime.now()+datetime.timedelta(0, sample)

# Create dataframe and first entry, administrator
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Admin'],
                   'chatId': [1234567890],
                   'TimeEnter': list(map(TimeOffset, random.sample(range(1, 15), 1)))})

FirstAnswer, SecondAnswer, ThirdAnswer, BIO = range(4)

async def start(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
    #ask User a question
    user = update.effective_user.first_name
    await update.message.reply_text(
        "Hi " + user + ", what's green and ski's from a mountain?"
    )
    return FirstAnswer
   
# Define the job callback function
async def startt(context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
    job = context.job
    chat_id = job.chat_id
    bot = context.bot
    
    # Simulate the command to start the conversation
    try: 
        """message = {
            'message_id': 1,
            'date': datetime.datetime.now().timestamp(),
            'chat': {'id': chat_id, 'type': 'private'},
            'text': '/start_conversation',
            'from': {'id': bot.id, 'is_bot': True, 'first_name': 'Bot'}
        }
        update = Update.de_json({'update_id': 0, 'message': message}, context.bot)"""
        update = Update.de_json({'message': {'chat': {'id': chat_id}, 'text': '/start'}}, bot)
    
        # Manually process the update
        #await bot.application.process_update(update)
        await  context.application.process_update(update)
    except Exception as e: print(e)
async def SecondStep(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> int:
async def ThirdStep(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> int:
async def cancel(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> int:

def setjob(row, context = ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    due = row['TimeEnter'] - datetime.datetime.now()
    chat_id = row['chatId']
    name = row['Name'] + '_' + row['TimeEnter'].strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S")
    context.job_queue.run_once(startt, due, chat_id=chat_id, 
                               name=name,
                               data=row['TimeEnter'].strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S"))
    return name

async def sched_df(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
    """Add the jobs in the df to the queue."""
    """Schedule new times."""
    df.TimeEnter = list(map(TimeOffset, random.sample(range(1, 15), len(df))))
    print(df)
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        try:
            setjob(row, context)
            text = "Entry " + str(index + 1) + " of df is successfully set!"
            print(text)
        except Exception as e: print(e)
        if len(df) == (1 + index):
            text = "All " + str(index + 1) + " set"
    await update.effective_message.reply_text(text)

def main() -> None:
    """Run the bot."""
    # Create the Application and pass it your bot's token.
    application = Application.builder().token(BOT_TOKEN).build()

    conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[CommandHandler('start', start)],
        states={
            SecondAnswer: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT, SecondStep)],
            ThirdAnswer: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT, ThirdStep)],
        },
        fallbacks=[CommandHandler("cancel", cancel)],
    )
    application.add_handler(conv_handler)

    application.add_handler(CommandHandler("scheddf", sched_df))

    # Run the bot until the user presses Ctrl-C
    application.run_polling(allowed_updates=Update.ALL_TYPES)
    #startt(application)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

I’ve created a program for a bot which has dataframe full of users that have previously requested to be added to the bot its message list. Now, using job_queue, the bot sends each of these users a message at a random point of the day. For testing, I didn't want to wait anywhere up to a full day so I decreased the time to 15s. The message requests the user for a response, like a quiz. I included a simple question to get the gist of it. The idea is that the users can respond to this message. The conversation as it should be is already made in a conversation handler, whose only entry_point right now is a CommandHandler with command ‘/start’. The rest of the ConversationHandler is simplified. However, I would like to trigger the conversation as soon as the bot sends the quiz-question.
Sending ‘/start’ from the bot its side doesn’t work. It doesn’t trigger anything. I used ChatGPT and it said to use process_update and a de_json function, as seen in startt, this seemed to some way send the message without showing it in the chat, but also didn’t trigger the conversationhandler. I looked into callbackhandlers, yet couldn’t figure out whether this was the right direction to look into.
Easy way to solve this is asking the user to send ‘/start’, but I hope there is a better solution. I would also like to cancel the conversation after a certain amount of time, yet this is a nice to have but I can imagine it could/should be done similarly.
Hope someone can help me, thanks in advance!
